# Box Api v2 java - How to reuse the access-token within 3600 secs

Tags: box-api

I am using Box Api v2 (java) for integrating my webapp with Box.com.

I forward the user to the authorize url

```
https://www.box.com/api/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=client-id
```

..and receive the 'code' at my redirect end-point. Using this code, I am able to get the access_token and refresh_token. I know that access_token is valid only for 1 hr.

But can I re-use the access_token within this 3600 sec period? 
eg:a user comes back within 30 minutes and tries to fetch/put files

In this scenario, I will need to create a new BoxClient.
So what is the recommended method of client authentication using the existing access token?

If answerer can paste code snippets using the box java api, it would be quite helpful.

Or is the refreshing to get new access_token and refresh_token, the only method available?

```
BoxClient client = new BoxClient(MY_CLIENT_ID, MY_CLIENT_SECRET);BoxOAuthManager mgr  = client.getOAuthManager();
  // This is refresh
BoxOAuthRequestObject requestObject = BoxOAuthRequestObject.refreshOAuthRequestObject(REFRESH_TOKEN, MY_CLIENT_ID, MY_CLIENT_SECRET);
BoxOAuthToken newToken = mgr.refreshOAuth(requestObject);
client.authenticate(newToken);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can re-use the access token within the 3600-second period.  A common pattern for web applications is to store the `access_token` and `refresh_token` (and optionally their expiration datetimes) in a database record associated with the user.

> > what is the recommended method of client authentication using the existing access token?

You'll use the same authentication method as when you first acquired the access token. You don't have to do anything special to reuse it.  If the `access_token` is expired, as determined by either an expiration timestamp comparison or 401 response, you can use the `refresh_token` to get a new token pair.  By refreshing and persisting the token pair in this manner you can keep the user authenticated indefinitely.

Comment: Yes, that's the theory and I want to do that.. My question was how to do this specifically in the context of Box.com java api v2. I only see 2 methods, the BoxOAuthManager.createOAuth which takes the grant token and gets the access + refresh tokens for the first time, or the BoxOAuthManager.refreshOAuth which gets a new access (and refresh) token..    I was looking for some java code snippet that shows the relevant methods in action.

Comment: There's a method, `BoxClient.authenticate(IAuthData)`, that appears to set the `access_token` for a given `BoxClient` instance.

Answer (score 0):

BoxOAuthToken accessToken = new BoxOAuthToken(Map) will work here.

```
// where Map contains
{
     "exprires_in":"3600",
     "token_type":"bearer",
     "refresh_token":"<refresh_token>",
     "access_token":"<access_token>"
}

Map authMap;
BoxOAuthToken accessToken = new BoxOAuthToken(authMap);
client.authenticate(newToken);
```